# SwiftUI/Combine Can't Initialize Class with ObservedObject

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm seriously struggling with what looks like a simple reference to an ObservedObject.
This SwiftUI app has a model for a view and it has a data store for capturing data from a remote
source. Both of these files are classes. Both conform to ObservableObject.

The issue is when attempting to refer to the data store within the model, I cannot get
the class initializer to work unless I refer to a brand new instance of the data store.

The skeletons:

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    //bunch of publishers and published properties

    init() {
        getTopLevel()
    }

    func getTopLevel() {
    ...
    }
}
```

and the view model:

```
final class ChatViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    let kAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    //bunch of properties

    lazy var session: MCSession = {
        let session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .none)
        session.delegate = self
        return session
    }()

    @ObservedObject var dataStore: DataStore

    override init() {
        self.dataStore = DataStore() // this is the issue
        super.init()

        //some notification center publishers for keyboard movement
    }
    //bunch of methods
}
```

If I remove the self.dataStore = DataStore() line I get the error :
Property 'self.dataStore' not initialized at super.init call

Of course if I leave it in, then it is a new DataStore which does me no good. I must be
missing something really basic here.

Xcode 11.5 iOS 13.5

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: you can pass an instance of `DataStore` in the init

Comment: I don't understand. I think that's what I have above. I don't want an instance of DataStore - I want the ObservableObject reference with the data.

Comment: The way I understood you issue was that you didn't want to instantiate a new `DataStore` for every instance of `ChatViewModel`. So, I'm suggesting - instantiate it outside the `ChatViewModel` as a singleton, and pass the instance into the init: `ChatViewModel(dataStore)`

Comment: I see. I'll try that.

Comment: For others - New Dev's suggestion of a Singleton does work for me. I'm still unclear why I would need that approach with Published properties, but it is working.